# Assign first register to zero and do not write

Tags: verilog, cpu-registers, test-bench

I'm a newbie in Verilog trying to create a register file which contains 32-bit registers. I'm able to write and read everything correctly, however, the first register (let's name it as R0) which is at address 5'b00000 must always be equal to 0 and must not be altered at any time. When reading it on a test bench, the problem comes up when R0 suddenly becomes "xxxxxxxx" instead of being 0 or 00000000. The rest of the registers were read correctly. What may I be doing wrong in the code and what could be the workaround for this one? Below is the code:

```
module regfile (
    clk,
    nrst,
    rd_addrA,
    rd_addrB,
    wr_addr,
    wr_en,
    wr_data,
    rd_dataA,
    rd_dataB
);

//Input and output ports
input wire clk;
input wire nrst;
input wire [4:0] rd_addrA;
input wire [4:0] rd_addrB;
input wire [4:0] wr_addr;
input wire wr_en;
input wire [31:0] wr_data;
output reg [31:0] rd_dataA;
output reg [31:0] rd_dataB;

reg [31:0] regfile[0:31];
integer i;

always @ (nrst)
    begin: RESET
        if(nrst == 0) begin
            for(i = 0; i < 32; i++) begin
                regfile[i] = 0;
            end
        end
    end

always @(rd_addrA or rd_addrB)
    begin: READ
        if(rd_addrA) begin
            case (rd_addrA)
                5'b00000: rd_dataA = regfile[0];
                5'b00001: rd_dataA = regfile[1];
                5'b00010: rd_dataA = regfile[2];
                5'b00011: rd_dataA = regfile[3];
                5'b00100: rd_dataA = regfile[4];
                5'b00101: rd_dataA = regfile[5];
                5'b00110: rd_dataA = regfile[6];
                5'b00111: rd_dataA = regfile[7];
                5'b01000: rd_dataA = regfile[8];
                5'b01001: rd_dataA = regfile[9];
                5'b01010: rd_dataA = regfile[10];
                5'b01011: rd_dataA = regfile[11];
                5'b01100: rd_dataA = regfile[12];
                5'b01101: rd_dataA = regfile[13];
                5'b01110: rd_dataA = regfile[14];
                5'b01111: rd_dataA = regfile[15];
                5'b10000: rd_dataA = regfile[16];
                5'b10001: rd_dataA = regfile[17];
                5'b10010: rd_dataA = regfile[18];
                5'b10011: rd_dataA = regfile[19];
                5'b10100: rd_dataA = regfile[20];
                5'b10101: rd_dataA = regfile[21];
                5'b10110: rd_dataA = regfile[22];
                5'b10111: rd_dataA = regfile[23];
                5'b11000: rd_dataA = regfile[24];
                5'b11001: rd_dataA = regfile[25];
                5'b11010: rd_dataA = regfile[26];
                5'b11011: rd_dataA = regfile[27];
                5'b11100: rd_dataA = regfile[28];
                5'b11101: rd_dataA = regfile[29];
                5'b11110: rd_dataA = regfile[30];
                5'b11111: rd_dataA = regfile[31];
                default: rd_dataA = 16'hXXXX;
            endcase
        end

        if(rd_addrB) begin
            case (rd_addrB)
                5'b00000: rd_dataB = regfile[0];
                5'b00001: rd_dataB = regfile[1];
                5'b00010: rd_dataB = regfile[2];
                5'b00011: rd_dataB = regfile[3];
                5'b00100: rd_dataB = regfile[4];
                5'b00101: rd_dataB = regfile[5];
                5'b00110: rd_dataB = regfile[6];
                5'b00111: rd_dataB = regfile[7];
                5'b01000: rd_dataB = regfile[8];
                5'b01001: rd_dataB = regfile[9];
                5'b01010: rd_dataB = regfile[10];
                5'b01011: rd_dataB = regfile[11];
                5'b01100: rd_dataB = regfile[12];
                5'b01101: rd_dataB = regfile[13];
                5'b01110: rd_dataB = regfile[14];
                5'b01111: rd_dataB = regfile[15];
                5'b10000: rd_dataB = regfile[16];
                5'b10001: rd_dataB = regfile[17];
                5'b10010: rd_dataB = regfile[18];
                5'b10011: rd_dataB = regfile[19];
                5'b10100: rd_dataB = regfile[20];
                5'b10101: rd_dataB = regfile[21];
                5'b10110: rd_dataB = regfile[22];
                5'b10111: rd_dataB = regfile[23];
                5'b11000: rd_dataB = regfile[24];
                5'b11001: rd_dataB = regfile[25];
                5'b11010: rd_dataB = regfile[26];
                5'b11011: rd_dataB = regfile[27];
                5'b11100: rd_dataB = regfile[28];
                5'b11101: rd_dataB = regfile[29];
                5'b11110: rd_dataB = regfile[30];
                5'b11111: rd_dataB = regfile[31];
                default: rd_dataB = 16'hXXXX;
            endcase
        end
    end

always @ (posedge clk)
    begin: WRITE
        if(wr_en == 1'b1) begin
            if(wr_addr != 5'd0) begin
                regfile[wr_addr] = #1 wr_data;
                //$display("%X", regfile[wr_addr]);
            end
            else begin
                $display("R0: %X", regfile[wr_addr]);
            end
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You should also have an initial condition if you want the register to contain a value no matter what.  This ensures that if the GSR or your reset is not hit for whatever reason that your `R0` will contain the value zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(rd_addrA)` is interpreted as `if(rd_addrA>0)`. Therefore reading `regfile[0]` unreachable. Because all entries are valid, you should not need the if-statement.

Other issues not related to your main question:

Your code is not synthesizable because `regfile` is assigned in two different always blocks. You need to merge the reset and write of `regfile` into one always block. `always @(posedge clk)` for synchronous reset (recommenced for FPGA). `always @(posedge clk or negedge nrst)` for asynchronous reset (recommenced for ASIC).

Specifying the sensitivity in combinational blocks is old style only requited for the 1995 edition. Since 2001 auto selectivity (`always @*` or the synonymous `always @(*)`) is the perfected way to start combinational blocks. Module header style recommendations have also changed since the Verilog-1995, so you should read up on that too. Verilog-1995 style is still valid and supported; just no longer perfected.

Synchronous logic (aka regs assigned by a clock or latch enable) should be assigned with non-blocking assignments (`<=`). You run a higher risk of behavioral miss-match between RTL and gates if you do not use blocking and non-blocking assignment appropriately.

Your case statements can be simplified to one line: `rd_dataA = regfile[rd_addrA];`. But do check your synthesize results as some synthesizers do not optimize as well with this style compared to a case-statement.

Comment: why do you recommend synchronous reset in FPGAs. I thought an asynchronous reset was the recommended technique for both FPGAs and ASICs

Comment: Most FPGAs have a limited number of flops with asynchronous reset/preset (if any); at least ones accessible to the designer. FPGAs commonly use `initial` blocks to define power-on-reset value. ASIC synthesizers typically ignore `initial` blocks which is why the use asynchronous reset.

Comment: I should clarify that asynchronous reset should mostly be used for power-on-reset. During normal operations synchronous reset  is recommended for most scenarios. Example: a counter should never asynchronously reset itself (meta-stability issues).

Comment: I was not aware that the initial block can be synthesized in FPGAs. Thanks for pointing it out. I guess there is always something new to learn everyday.